# How do I get the full text from getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo() so that I can show the license to user when offline?

Tags: android, google-api, offline

*scenario:* when app is connected to the internet it shows license text but user has no license to read when app is offline

*my problem:* So I wanted to somehow retrieve the license text so that I can save it to a .txt file in android app project n display license to user from it(for offline read)

*what I tried:* I am unable to get the complete license text from [`getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(android.content.Context)) when I tried to `Log.d()` it only shows some text n not the complete license text which is actually huge

*My goal is to get the license text which can be copy pasted to a txt file*

Comment: How would you keep the license up to date, if you put it in your APK? I don't think, this is a good approach. Maybe you should require the user to turn on Internet, before confirming any license. `Log.d()` always cuts of the String if it gets to long. But the String returned by `getOpenSourceSoftwareLic‌​enseInfo()` should contain the complete license text.

Comment: @AlbAtNf I will always display the licence text using getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo() when user is online. User should also have access to the licence when he is offline is what I have learned after going through this [blog's comments](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/open-source-licenses-and-android/)

Comment: **I just wanted to update:** Once the user is signed in using Google drive account in my app, _I somehow get the license text even in offline mode from getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo()_. So I need not save the license text in a file to show user for offline access